# Can't Build Signed Application, Only Unsigned Works, failed to convert to dalvik format

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

Please read all before deleting or voting down, thanks :)

I have an app that uses:

```
1-ActionBarSherlock
2-ViewPaerIndicator
3-PullToRefresh
```

When I try to build a signed version of it, fails with 'Failed to convert to dalvik format'

the problem is that I have no errors, nor lint warning

can anybody help with how to debug it or how to solve this,

I've followed many answers in here but nothing really helped,

The only common thing in the above dependencies that I know; is the support library, which I made sure that it's the same version in both ViewPagerIndicator and ABS, I tried to remove it from any of the 2 dependencies but the build failed, even for the unsigned version.

**Update:**

Update I found a solution for this, I removed the **Support Lib. v13** and replaced it with **V4** in all occurrences and it worked.

Although I found some answer that said don't use v13 and v4 together, but this wasn't my case I was only using v.13

Answer (score 0):

Update I found a solution for this, I removed the Support Lib. V13 and replaced it with V4 in all occurrences and it worked.